# File permission issue from s3 bucket mounted on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb

I have mounted an s3 bucket to an ec2 machine where a database (MariaDB) is running. I am creating csv files in the s3 bucket from a Lambda function through the boto3 `put_object()` method and trying to load the file into the database using the same Lambda function with `LOAD DATA INFILE` command but I am getting RDBMS error as `Permission denied`.

The csv files when seen on ec2 reads the permission as:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root root  517 Mar  7 13:41 dummy3.csv
```

I tried setting ACLs as 'public-read' on the object but the error persists. Am I missing something here?

Note that when I change permission of the file on ec2 to `755` the file get loaded successfully to the database from the same Lambda function.

How to provide required permission to s3 object while creating?

Comment: What are you using to mount the S3 bucket on the EC2 instance? This is an unusual way of accessing S3, since S3 does not translate directly to Linux file permissions. Perhaps the software you are using to mount S3 has some documentation about how it handles permission mapping between s3 and Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
I have followed below as reference 
  https://cloudkul.com/blog/mounting-s3-bucket-linux-ec2-instance/

Comment: This is sorted now. Thanks for the support.
Added group id of the User through which MariaDB Service was running while mounting the S3 Bucket.

Comment: Great! You are welcome to add your own Answer to assist future readers.